# Run Query to MySQL from a Bash Script

Tags: mysql, bash

please help, whats wrong?

> sudo -u root /etc/scripts/mysql.sh root 111111

```
#!/bin/bash 
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=111111
mysql 1<< EOF
INSERT INTO
table1(id)
SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM table1;
EOF
```

Comment: What is the error essage?

Comment: nothing change, insert in mysql

Comment: Try `mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=111111 -e"INSERT INTO
table1(id)
SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM table1;"`

Comment: how select db "1"? ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected

Comment: add it before -e and after your password `mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=111111 <db_name> -e"INSERT INTO table1(id) SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM table1;"`

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token `1 '

Comment: #!/bin/bash
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=111111 <1> -e"INSERT INTO table1(id) SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM table1;"

Comment: sorry remove < and >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just invoke MySQL once and specify the default database:

```
#!/bin/bash 
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=111111 1 << EOF
INSERT INTO
table1(id)
SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM table1;
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

USER='root'
PASS='root123'

mysql -u$USER -p$PASS mydb -e"insert into table1 (id) select (max(id) + 1) from table1;"
```

Note: As you are executing sql from same server so no need of localhost.

Now use as from directory where your script exists-

```
sh myscript.sh
```